# Modification of distribution function

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, density-function

I had been given a density function of "probability of a computation time".

The density function is defined as

[image]

I have computed the distribution function for this density function, it should be

[image]

The problem is, that I'm supposed to come up with a modified distribution function for a case when the computation time is 30% faster. What do I modify so it is true? I'm not sure where to start. Can you point me in the right direction? Thank you. Also sorry for my vague terms, im not really familiar with these probability terms in english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who stumles upon this.

The solution is pretty simple. You just need to realize what x means in this case. It is number of seconds. So I a case where Computing takes 30% less then y = 0.7x
So the distribution function is the same, you just substitute x for 0.7x